# Word for "leisure/enjoyable activity"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word for that? (e.g. traveling, painting, playing a sport, etc.)

Example:

> A [...] is only worthy if you take pleasure from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*pastime*, *hobby*, *interest*, *pursuit*, *avocation*, *spare-time activity*